# English translation of Omar Khayyám's mathematical work

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, reference-request, translations

Is there any current English translation of the mathematical works of [Omar Khayyám](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Khayy%C3%A1m)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that there is an adequate English translation of al-Khayyāmī's famous treatise on Algebra. If you read French there is a good scholarly translation by Roshdi Rashed et Ahmad Djebbar, "L’Oeuvre algébrique d’al-Khayyām", Aleppo 1981